# Is it necessary to call SDL_Quit() at the end of the game?

Tags: sdl2

Is it necessary to call `SDL_Quit()` at the end of the game? Doesn't C/C++ handle all the variables destruction and memory freeing at the end of a program?

Comment: Not every resource you acquire is a variable - just something for you to think about.